# Find the voltage at FE/OX interface of FEFET transistor

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

I've been reading an article about this type of transistor and I can equation the circuit when we just consider the voltage at the interface between the ferroelectric capacitor and the MOS capacitor. However, the authors present the MOS capacitor as the series combination of the capacitance between the drain and the gate interface and the capacitance between the interface and the source.

They present the following equation:

$$
dV_{IS} = \frac{dV_{GS}}{1-\frac{C_{GI}}{|C_{FE}|}} - \frac{dV_{DS}}{\frac{{|C_{FE}|-C_{GI}}}{C_{GDI}}}
$$

I've tried to model it as in the diagram below, but I still can't find the above solution as I don't believe I can use Thevénin  as the circuit isn't linear. Could anyone help, please?

Here's a link to the article: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7970179

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcfYmI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Might be useful to link the article.